# Java - Class Chaining

Tags: java, chaining

Assume that you have following Classes with static defined methods.

- `kubeUtils`

  - KubeUtils
  - `controllers`

    - ConfigMapUtils
    - DeploymentUtils
    - ...
  - `objects`

    - PodUtils
    - NamespaceUtils
    - ....

each class has some methods like

```
public static void waitUntilServiceIsPresent(String serviceName){
  // implementation...
}

public static void waitUntilServiceDeletion(String serviceName){
  // implementation...
}

public static void waitUntilServiceIsUpdated(String serviceName){
  // implementation...
}

and so on...
```

So in the user view we need to call it like: `ServiceUtils.waitUntilServiceIsPresent(serviceName);`

What i need for syntax sugar will be using Class chaining but i have no idea how i can possibly do it. Example:

```
KubeUtils.ServiceUtils.waitUntilServiceIsPresent(serviceName)

or 

KubeUtils.getServiceUtils.waitUntilServicePresent(serviceName)
```

remember that i have only static methods in these classes and i do not want to use composition. My goal is to use this methods without creating an object. Hope, my explanation is clear.

Comment: It's not clear, truth be told.

Comment: Is there an aggregation? That means, e.g, is KubeUtils has an attribute of class type ServiceUtils?

Comment: I’m not sure why you are determined to use static methods.  Large numbers of static methods are usually a poor design.  `ServiceMonitor` or `ServiceWatcher` would be a much more informative name than ServiceUtils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go ahead and say that I don't think it's good practice, but as an exercise: You can achieve this by having inner classes:

```
public class KubeUtils {
    public static class ServiceUtils {
        public static void waitUntilServiceIsPresent(String serviceName){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
KubeUtils.ServiceUtils.waitUtilServiceIsPresent(...);
```

---

For better practice, I would maybe use a package structure to structure your utility classes like so:

```
com.domain.project
├── kube
│   ├── ServiceUtil
│   └── FooUtil
└── bar
    └── BazUtil
```

Comment: Currently i have it in the structure and classes organized well but that second approach would not solve. It will be the same calling `ServiceUtil.someMethod()` or  `BazUtil.someMethod()`. It will be just structured. Correct?